# pass function from class without starting it python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I need to run two functions with the `threading` module

you're able to do this `Thread(target=my_func)`

but i want the function from a class (imported class) so i tried `Thread(target=a_class.my_func)`

but it didn't worked, then i tried `Thread(target=a_class.my_func())`

but this one starts to run the function because i called it , and this is an infinite loop so the next function would never run.

how do i supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the class methods, like this:

```
import threading

def my_func(self):
    a_class.my_func()

def my_other_func(self):
    a_class.my_other_func()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=my_func)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=my_other_func)
```